# Symfony4 Doctrine ODM - ManyToMany get empty

Tags: symfony, symfony4, doctrine-odm, odm

I have a problem with my many to many relations

I have a User class that can be on multiple Teams
and a class Team that can have multiple Users

```
class User

    /**
     * @var Collection
     * @ODM\ReferenceMany(
     *     targetDocument="App\Model\Document\Team",
     *     mappedBy="members",
     *     strategy="setArray"
     * )
     */
    protected $teams;
```

---

```
class Team

    /**
     * @var Collection|null
     * @ODM\ReferenceMany(
     *     targetDocument="App\Model\Document\User",
     *     inversedBy="teams",
     *     strategy="setArray",
     *     sort={"username": "asc"},
     *     cascade={"persist"}
     * )
     */
    protected $members;
```

With these annotations, when I add members User to the team and I do a `getMembers` on an instance of Team, it works.
BUT, when I have an instance of a User (that's a member of a Team) the `getTeams` return nothing (empty PersistentCollection)

The reference is stored on the Teams Document, as an array of references

```
"members" : [ 
    {
        "$ref" : "User",
        "$id" : ObjectId("XXX"),
        "$db" : "readDat"
    }
],
```

I don't understand, with the annotations as they are now, I thought Doctrine would do something like this `db.getCollection('Team').find({"members.$id":ObjectId("XXX")})`
to have the teams but it seems not.

On the other hand, I tried to inverse the `mappedBy` and `inversedBy`, I can't even `getMembers` (on a Team object) or `getTeams` (on a User object) anymore, both are empty Collection.

How can I have a good Many to Many (without duplicate the references in both Document) ?

Comment: Have you used $teams = $user->getTeams()->toArray();?

Comment: Wow, seems it works, thank you !. Dunno why my twig foreach and my `dump` don't see the elements, but with `dump($user->getTeams()->toArray())` I see my team.
I'll change my twig to use toArray as well. I still don't understand why it's empty if I don't add the toArray.

Comment: It's about lazy hydration. Your collection is not initialized until it has to. When you call toArray() in fact you force the collection to get initialized.

Comment: Oh okay, I had no idea about that. Is there a proper way to force the collection to be initialized while keeping the Collection class instance ? Maybe it's not good idea though, but If I can stay with ArrayCollection, I can have all the ArrayCollection methods. I can stil create a new ArrayCollection like this though `new ArrayCollection($user->getTeams()->toArray())` but that's not "clean", imo.

Comment: @Etshy just don't (var_)dump the collection, use it normally (i.e. foreach over it, filter or any other method from the `Collection` interface) and it will work

Comment: @malarzm I'm not sure it works in twig. Before I change my twig to `{% for team in user.teams.toArray %}` nothing was shown. Maybe in Php, it could works though. I'll do more tests on my free time later.